# Running program using testNG, First time added invalid data in the fields then Clear and then valid credentials to login

Tags: selenium, onclick, testng

**Error Coming while executing the Script and below I have mentioned the script that I had run please check and let me know why this error being faced**

```
java.io.IOException: Access is denied
        at java.base/java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)       at java.base/java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.Utils.writeFile(Utils.java:173)
        at org.testng.internal.Utils.writeFile(Utils.java:149)          atorg.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter.generateLog(TestHTMLReporter.java:320)          atorg.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter.onFinish(TestHTMLReporter.java:40)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.fireEvent(TestRunner.java:1250)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:1041)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:628)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
```

**CODE, which I run to execute the Test and above is the error, Error Coming while executing the Script above and below I have mentioned the script that I had run please check and let me know why this error being faced**

```
 package TestNG;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class testng {

         WebDriver driver;          

            // Method 1: Open Brower say Firefox            
            @Test (priority = 1)        
            public void openBrowser() {             
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();               

           // public void launch() {                
                driver.get("URL");                      
            }       


        @Test (priority = 2)

         public void one() throws InterruptedException {



              driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='user_login']")).sendKeys("Invalid Email");



             driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='user_login_password']")).sendKeys("Invalid Password");



             driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='user_login_btn']")).click();



              System.out.println("Error has occur wrong credentials");
         }

         @Test (priority = 3)

          public void two() {

                  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='user_login']")).clear();
                  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='user_login_password']")).clear();
                  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='user_login']")).sendKeys("Valid");
                  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='user_login_password']")).sendKeys("Valid");
                  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='user_login_btn']")).click();
```

Comment: Please share your code block, which is failing, where you create a file

Comment: Added, please check

Comment: try to run your script as Admin

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the path of geckodriver.
Please set the driver path in the method **openBrowser()**

Driver path can be set by using the code below:

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path of geckodriver");
 driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```